# HQL in clause for component mapping

Tags: java, hibernate

I am executing a simple select HQL query

```
from CertObjRel where certificatePrimary in (:certificatePrimaryList)  
where certificatePrimaryList is a java arrayList of certificatePrimary
```

CertificatePrimary class:

```
class CertificatePrimary implements Serializable{

    //private int primaryId;
    private String certificateId;
    private Short trsSequenceNbr;

    public String getCertificateId() {
        return certificateId;
    }

    public Short getTrsSequenceNbr() {
        return trsSequenceNbr;
    }

    public void setCertificateId(String certificateId) {
        this.certificateId = certificateId;
    }

    public void setTrsSequenceNbr(Short trsSequenceNbr) {
        this.trsSequenceNbr = trsSequenceNbr;
    }

}
```

CertObjRelMapping contains CertificatePrimary as component

CertObjRel.hbm.xml

```
<component name="certificatePrimary" class="com.csc.exceed.certificate.domain.CertificatePrimary">
    <property name="certificateId" type="java.lang.String" column="CERT_ID" length="36" not-null="true"/> 
    <property name="trsSequenceNbr" type="java.lang.Short" column="CERT_TRS_SEQ_NBR" />
</component>
```

I am getting the following error

```
DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=(;RT_TRS_SEQ_NBR) in (;<values>, DRIVER=3.50.152
```

This error is generated after parameter are binded.

Answer (score 1):

In my knowledge **HQL** `in` clouse does't support the beans. So, Modify your query as below to make use of `certificateId` inside the `CertificatePrimary` which is a string.

`from CertObjRel where certificatePrimary.certificateId in (:certificatePrimaryIdList)`

`certificatePrimaryIdList` should be the `string` **which is coma separated list of ids formed by iterating the `certificatePrimaryList`** for example `'A','B','C'`.

Comment: I need to retrieve record for a combination of certificateID and trsSequenceNbr. This was the reason of creating a component certificatePrimary. Is there any other work around as even SQL IN clause support multi column only for certain specific database.